# Visual Studio Debugger does not automatically attach to local Service Fabric Service

Tags: visual-studio, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I've created a ASP.NET Core Service Fabric Stateful app and I'm deploying it to a local 3-node cluster using F5 ("Start Debugging").  The deployment succeeds and the service is up.  However, Visual Studio does not automatically attach to my service.  I have to manually click "Attach to Process" and find my service process.  Does anyone know why?

The same thing happens with the Voting sample application that they provide.

Some relevant details:

- I'm using VS 2019, .NET Core 3.0
- I'm running VS as an Admin
- I've set the Service Fabric app as the "Startup" project (not the services)
- By default, the app's "Debugger to launch" was set to "Debugger not supported".  I had to set it to "Start" and "Debugger Type" to "Managed Only"

Answer (score 0):

This used to work for me, too. I think it broke when I upgraded my local Service Fabric from 6.3 to 7.0. If you are on 7.0 but don't need any of it's new features, try downgrading to 6.5.